# Solution for 3D wave equation for vector fields

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, vector-analysis

I've been trying to find the solution to the 3-D wave equation for **vector** fields, that is:

$$\nabla^2 \vec{u}(\vec{x}, t) = \frac{1}{c^2} \frac{\partial^2 \vec{u}(\vec{x}, t)}{\partial t^2}$$

Given initial conditions 
$$\vec{u}(\vec{x},0)=\vec{\Phi}(\vec{x})$$
$$\left. \frac{\partial\vec{u}(\vec{x},t)}{\partial t}\right|_{t=0}=\vec{\Psi}(\vec{x}) $$

Whatever sources I found so far take me to Kirchoff's formula, which is the solution for the 3D wave equation for **scalar** fields. I've been trying to obtain the solution for vector fields from that, considering that each Cartesian component of a vector field is a scalar.

I've gotten so far [$B(\vec{x},ct)$ being the sphere with center at $\vec{x}$ and with a radius $ct$]:

[Corrected: $ct \vec{\Psi}(\vec{y})$ to $t \vec{\Psi}(\vec{y})$]

$$\vec{u}(\vec{x}, t) = \frac {1} {4 \pi c^2t^2} \oint_{\partial B(\vec{x}, ct)} [\vec{\Phi}(\vec{y}) + t \vec{\Psi}(\vec{y}) + \mathbb{X}]\space dS(\vec{y})$$
Where using Cartesian coordinates $i, j, k$, 
$$\mathbb{X} = (\nabla\Phi_i(\vec{y})\cdot(\vec{y}-\vec{x}))\hat{i} + (\nabla\Phi_j(\vec{y})\cdot(\vec{y}-\vec{x}))\hat{j} + (\nabla\Phi_k(\vec{y})\cdot(\vec{y}-\vec{x}))\hat{k}$$

My vector math is quite shaky -- so I'd like to ask:

1. Is my derivation correct so far?
2. Can $\mathbb{X}$ or $\oint \mathbb{X}$ be simplified further, and made independent of the coordinate system?

Any corrections or pointers to some reference material with the right answer will be appreciated.

Thanks...

Thanks to @WillieWong here is the expression I was trying to get to:
$$\vec{u}(\vec{x}, t) = 
  \frac {1} {4 \pi c^2t^2} 
    \oint_{\partial B(\vec{x}, ct)} \left(
       \vec{\Phi}(\vec{y}) 
       + t \vec{\Psi}(\vec{y}) 
       + \left[ \left(\vec{y} - \vec{x}\right)\cdot\nabla\right]\vec{\Phi}(\vec{y})
    \right)\space dS(\vec{y})$$

Comment: No, it is not right. What's up with the factor of $\sqrt{3}$? And why the vector $\vec{q}$? If you examine the last term inside the integrand, you've now made the gradient of a scalar function, and taken its dot product with a vector. This makes it a **scalar**, not a **vector**!

Comment: Oops! @Willie Wong you are right of course! What I am actually looking for is $$(\nabla \Phi_i(\vec{y})\cdot (\vec{y} - \vec{x}))\hat{i} + \nabla (\Phi_j(\vec{y})\cdot (\vec{y} - \vec{x}))\hat{j} + (\nabla \Phi_k(\vec{y})\cdot (\vec{y} - \vec{x})\hat{k} $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applying the scalar Kirchoff's formula, you have that for $\vec{u} = (u_1, \ldots, u_d)$ that for each component $i$

$$ u_i(\vec{x},t) = \frac{1}{4\pi c^2 t^2} \oint_{\partial B(\vec{x},ct)} \left[ ct \Psi_i(\vec{y}) + \Phi_i(\vec{y}) + (\vec{y} - \vec{x}) \cdot \nabla \Phi_i(y) \right] \mathrm{d}S(\vec{y}) $$

So that putting everything in its place you have that

$$ \vec{u}(\vec{x},t) = \frac{1}{4\pi c^2 t^2} \oint_{\partial B(\vec{x},ct)} \left\{ ct \vec{\Psi}(\vec{y}) + \vec{\Phi}(\vec{y}) + \left[(\vec{y} - \vec{x}) \cdot \nabla\right] \vec{\Phi}(y) \right\} \mathrm{d}S(\vec{y}) $$

where

$$ \left[(\vec{y} - \vec{x}) \cdot \nabla\right] \vec{\Phi}(y) = \sum_{j = 1}^3(y_j - x_j)\partial_j \vec{\Phi}(y) $$

with the right hand side evaluated component-wise.